# How can we prove that the following theorem is valid for almost perfect secrecy?

Tags: encryption, perfect-secrecy

We have the following theorem:

> Let $\Pi$ be a perfectly-secret scheme over message space $M$, and let $K$ be determined by $Gen$. Then $|K| ≥ |M|$.

How can we prove that the above theorem is valid for almost perfect secrecy? The definition for almost perfect secrecy is as follows:

> The encryption scheme $\Pi = (Gen,Enc,Dec)$ over a message space $M$
>   is **almost perfectly secret** or **$\varepsilon$-perfectly secret**
>   if for every probability distribution over $M$, $\forall m \in M$ and
>   $\forall c \in C$ for which $Pr[C = c] > 0$ and for a constant
>   $\varepsilon < 1$:
>
> $$|Pr[M = m|C = c] - Pr[M = m]| < \varepsilon$$

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the proof of the original statement and try to adapt it?

Comment: The definitions seem to be missing some details. What is K? What is C and c, and how can M = m if m is an element in M?

Comment: ... my point is that we can of course try to guess, but it might be easier to answer your question if you are a bit more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt an arbitrary message to get a ciphertext $c$, then use all keys to decrypt $c$. If $|K| \lt |M|$, there exists a message $m$ which can not be decrypted from $c$ using any key.

Then $|\Pr[M=m\mid C=c]-\Pr[M=m]| = \Pr[M=m]$ and since we can assign an arbitrary distribution to our message space, we can make $\Pr[M=m] > \epsilon$. This violates your definition of $\epsilon$-perfect secrecy, thus we must have $|K| \geq |M|$.

Note that there is a different definition of an $\epsilon$-perfect secrecy, the one requiring that an adversary playing a game could not succeed with a probability higher than $\frac{1}{2} + \epsilon$. Such definition allows to have fewer keys than messages.
For more information, have a look at [Almost (epsilon) perfect secrecy - lower bound of keyspace size](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/74698/almost-epsilon-perfect-secrecy-lower-bound-of-keyspace-size)

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira Why should the last statement of your comment be true? Each term in a sum is not conditioning on c anymore. $Pr(m | c)$ indicates the probability that a message m was encrypted to the observed ciphertext c. I chose a message m that **can not** be encrypted to c. So if I observe a ciphertext c, then I know for sure that the plaintext message is not m, i.e. $P(m | c) = 0$

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira For a fair dice Pr(D=2) + Pr(D=4) is 2/6, but Pr(D=2k | D<5) is 1/2