# Almost (epsilon) perfect secrecy - lower bound of keyspace size

Tags: perfect-secrecy

As a newcomer to cryptography, I'm working on Exercise 2.12 in the book, *Introduction to Modern Cryptography*.[image: It looks like this:]

Using the proof of the theorem that says if $E$ is a perfectly secret encryption scheme, then $\lvert K\rvert \geq \lvert M\rvert$),
I've shown that the lower bound for the size of the keyspace is as below:
$$\lvert K\rvert \geq (1-\epsilon)\lvert M\rvert$$

But here's the problem: I proved this under the condition that $$\lvert\Pr[M=m\mid C=c]-\Pr[M=m]\rvert\leq\epsilon$$

So I think I should show that this definition is equivalent to the condition given in the exercise.

**My question** is whether the two definitions are equivalent, and if so, how can I prove it?

Comment: I'm curious how you proved it. If $|K|$ < $|M|$ there will be an impossible message-ciphertext pair (m, c). Since we can freely choose a distribution for $M$, let $P(m) > \epsilon$. Then $P(m) - P(m | c)$ > $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: the two definitions are **not** equivalent.

Long answer:

- The condition $|\Pr[M=m\mid C=c]-\Pr[M=m]|\leq\epsilon$ doesn't allow us to have less keys than messages. Encrypt an arbitrary message to get a ciphertext $c$, then use all keys to decrypt $c$. If $|K| \lt |M|$, there exists a message $m$ which can not be decrypted from $c$ using any key.
  Then $|\Pr[M=m\mid C=c]-\Pr[M=m]| = \Pr[M=m]$ and since we can assign an arbitrary distribution to our message space, we can make $\Pr[M=m] > \epsilon$
- The definition of $\epsilon$-perfect secrecy given in the book (the one you show in the image) does allow us to have fewer keys than messages. For example:

  Suppose the message space $M$ contains all 4 English letter words, $|M|$ = $26^4$. Let's use a one-time-pad encryption scheme without the identity key, thus $|K|$ = $|M| - 1$.

  Any adversary playing a game will choose two messages $m_0$, $m_1$. If our returned ciphertext $c=m_0$ the adversary knows for sure that the encrypted message is $m_1$. If our returned ciphertext $c=m_1$ the adversary knows for sure that the encrypted message is $m_0$. But if we return any other ciphertext, the one-time-pad scheme ensures that the best an adversary can do is to make a random guess. Therefore, the probability for an adversary to win a game is not greater than

  $1 \cdot \Pr(c \in \{m_0, m_1\}) + \frac{1}{2} \cdot (1 - \Pr(c \in \{m_0, m_1\}))$ = $\frac{1}{2} + \Pr(c \in \{m_0, m_1\}) \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2|K|}$

  Thus, this scheme achieves $\epsilon$ perfect secrecy if $\epsilon \geq \frac{1}{2|M-1|}$
- Let's find a lower bound for $\epsilon$. Suppose an adversary chooses $m_0$ and $m_1$ uniformly at random. Upon receiving a ciphertext $c$ it computes $M_c = \{ m | \exists k. enc_k(m) = c\}$ (it might be computationally infeasible to compute $M_c$, but we're not concerned about computational resources in this exercise).

  Note that at least one of $m_0, m_1$ is in $M_c$. If some $m_i \not \in M_c$ the adversary knows for sure that the encrypted message is the other one. If both messages are in $M_c$, the adversary makes a random guess.

  The probability of such adversary succeeding is
  $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \Pr(m_0, m_1 \in M_c) + 1 \cdot (1-\Pr(m_0, m_1 \in M_c))$ = $ 1 - \Pr(m_o, m_1 \in M_c) \cdot \frac{1}{2}$

  Let's estimate $\Pr(m_0, m_1 \in M_c)$ - the probability that both messages are in $M_c$. One message will certainly be in $M_c$ because we encrypted it to $c$, the other message is chosen uniformly at random from $M$, so the probability of both being in $M_c$ is $|M_c| / |M| \leq |K| / |M|$

  Thus an adversary can win a game with a probability $p \geq 1 - |K| / |M| \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot (|M| - |K|) / |M|$. If we want $\epsilon$ secrecy we must have $\frac{1}{2} + \epsilon \geq p$ which implies that:

  **$|K| \geq |M| \cdot (1-2\epsilon)$**

  note that I have not shown this lower bound is attainable.

Comment: can you please provide the details for the sake of other users reading this interesting question?

Comment: @kodlu I had to revise my knowledge about the $\epsilon$-perfect secrecy and updated my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been discussed in [*Beating Shannon requires BOTH
efficient adversaries AND non-zero advantage* by Yevgeniy Dodis, NYU, 2012/053](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/053).

### First, consider the Definition 1 and Remark 2. Remark 2 is as same as $\Pr[\mathsf{PrivK}^{\mathsf{eav}}_{\mathcal{A},\mathsf{\Pi}}]\leq\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon$.

[image]

---

### Then consider the second part of the Theorem 1 without decryption error (for exactly being same as the thing that the question wants).

[image]

---

### In the following, the proof is explained. Again, you can omit decryption error (for exactly being the same as the thing that the question wants).

[image]

---